# Why does GRUB fail to auto-boot when no keyboard is connected?

Tags: grub2

**Question:** Why does GRUB fail to auto-boot when no keyboard is connected?

**Background:** I've been running a Debian bullseye for over a year now, and GRUB has always worked as intended - upon boot, it shows the menu for five seconds, then selects the default option. This worked regardless of whether or not I had a keyboard plugged in during boot. I recently plugged in a keyboard to manage the system locally, updated the kernel from `5.10.0-15` to `5.10.0-19`, and rebooted. As expected, GRUB showed the timeout, then auto-booted into the latest kernel.

Some time later, I unplugged the keyboard. Upon rebooting the system (via ssh), I noticed the system failed to come back online. I went to check, and the system was stuck on the GRUB menu. I plugged a keyboard in, selected the default option, and logged in. Everything worked fine. I rebooted again (with the keyboard plugged in), and watched it reboot, count down from 5, then auto-boot back in to the expected kernel. Next, I entered `sleep 10; sudo reboot` and unplugged the keyboard, thinking maybe it was caused by ssh-triggered reboots. But sure enough, upon booting, GRUB showed no countdown, and just remained at the menu screen.

*How can I go back to the intended behavior of auto-booting even without a keyboard plugged in?* As a temporary workaround, I'm just leaving an unused keyboard plugged in. With that in place, rebooting (even remotely via ssh) still allows the system to come back online without local keypresses.

**Additional Details:**

```
$ sudo grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-3~deb11u2
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/default/grub
...
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
...
```

Originally the config read `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` and omitted `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT`. The changes above reflect a failed attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with Fedora 38. Did you eventually solve the problem?

Comment: @minils Nope; still just leaving a keyboard plugged in.

Comment: I was wondering if it might be an issue concerning the mainboard. Did you coincidentally check your BIOS/UEFI for a related setting? My problematic machine runs on an MSI board. I have another one that boots fine without keyboard running with a different mainboard.